# Qual è il significato di "occhi stretti"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> A un certo punto mi lanciò uno sguardo dei suoi, fermo, con gli **occhi stretti**, e si diresse verso la palazzina dove abitava don Achille.

Malgrado aver letto tutte le accezioni di ["stretto" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stretto1/), non riesco a capire il significato dell'espressione "occhi stretti" in questo brano. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: strizzando un poco gli occhi con espressione "intensa"?

Comment: [Clint Eastwood](http://www.vedovintage.it/wp-content/uploads/clinteastwood-il-buono-il-brutto-il-cattivo.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Occhi stretti" in questo caso vuol dire "serrati" o "semichiusi".
Mancava poco che gli occhi fossero completamente chiusi.

Answer (score 1):

Nella Treccani:

> strétto1 agg. [part. pass. di stringere, che continua il lat. strĭctus, part. pass. di stringĕre]. – 1. a. Premuto, serrato fortemente

Si intendono appunto gli occhi serrati (anche se più propriamente sono le palpebre a essere serrate).

Però anche la seconda definizione è appropriata:

> 2. Di dimensioni ridotte nel senso della larghezza, non ampio, angusto

Infatti gli occhi serrati diventano più stretti del normale, riducendosi a due linee.

In entrambi i casi le due definizioni ci riportano alla stessa azione.